# Binance <Api-key format invalid.> with Python requests but works with curl

Tags: python-3.x, curl, python-requests, binance

I'm trying to put an order on Binance testnet using python requests. It always throws `{"code":-2014,"msg":"API-key format invalid."}`. But the same url returns data successfully when used with curl. Can somebody please point out what's wrong with my python requests code?

```
API_KEY= <api_key>
SECRET= <password>

import time
import requests
import hashlib
import hmac

def hashing(query_string):
    return hmac.new(SECRET.encode('utf-8'), 
                    query_string.encode('utf-8'), 
                    hashlib.sha256).hexdigest()

base_url = "https://testnet.binance.vision"
api_path = "/api/v3/order"
timestamp = int(time.time()*1000)
msg = "symbol=BNBUSDT&side=BUY&type=LIMIT&quantity=1&timeInForce=GTC&price=200&timestamp={}".format(timestamp)
msg_hash = hashing(msg)

url = f"{base_url}{api_path}?{msg}&signature={msg_hash}"

print(url)

headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8',
                    'X-MBX-APIKEY': API_KEY}

print("\nusing python-requests")
with requests.Session() as session:
    session.headers.update(headers)
    resp = session.put(url)
    print(resp)


print("\nusing curl")
!curl -H "X-MBX-APIKEY: {API_KEY}" -X POST "{url}"
```

colab link: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1qPuDK_mGBchpoD4cVbq6oKvt_WY4nX71?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

So a few things.

1. In your curl, the only headers you have is the `X-MBX-APIKEY` and not the content type. So I would try changing that accordingly.
2. Also in the curl, you are performing a POST request and not a PUT. I would change that as well.
3. I'm not sure if the curl is encoding anything differently. I would pass through url parameters differently and let requests handle it.

Thus,

```py
params = {
    'symbol': 'BNBUSDT',
    'side': 'BUY',
    'type': 'LIMIT',
    'quantity': '1',
    'timeInForce': 'GTC',
    'price': '200',
    'timestamp': timestamp,
    'signature': msg_hash
}

headers = {
    'X-MBX-APIKEY': API_KEY
}

r = requests.post(base_url+api_path, params=params, headers=headers)
```

This is assuming your curl is working properly though. I see in your colab that the curl is returning an error. Usually one also needs to pass in the `data` keyword argument with a POST, I would refer back to the binance api documentation.

Note, to recover the url of the request, you can `print(r.url)`, which is `https://testnet.binance.vision/api/v3/order?symbol=BNBUSDT&side=BUY&type=LIMIT&quantity=1&timeInForce=GTC&price=200&timestamp=X&signature=XX`